# chrome : Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when parsing a small script (=10000 concatenated strings)

Tags: javascript, string, google-chrome, stack-overflow

I got a css that was previously loaded using htmlhttprequest.
For some reason I now preferred to store it in a script.
So I double quoted every line of it and chained them with a +

```
var myfile = {
 "filename":"mystyle.css",
 "content":
  "line1" +
  "line2" +
  ...
  "line10000" +
}
```

Chrome failed at parsing this very simple script and throws a
Maximum call stack size exceeded

I read some warnings about very large array but there this is not an array and size is quite low so I wonder :

what is happening?
how are you supposed to break a text to insert it into a script ?

If you want to recreate the broken script

```
var script = 'var myfile={"filename":"mystyle.css",\n"content":' + Array(10000).join('"                    .contentHeader{background-color:red;color:blue;}" + \n') + '""}; console.log(myfile);';
```

Notice that there's no problem when dealing with a 10000 entries array

Comment: Why would you want to load CSS that way, what's wrong with a regular `link` tag?

Comment: because this is not really a css but rather a file that needs to be processed to get a css